# out of memory error when use the VisualVm to analysis heap dump

Tags: jvm, visualvm, jvisualvm

when use the heap dump of visualVm, there is an option to see all the instances of a specific class, but when the instances is to much, i got this error:

out of memory in heap walker：
To avoid this error，increase the -Xmx value in the etc/netbeans.conf file in NetBeans IDE installation directory.

But the error should have nothing to do with the netbeans.conf, it should be something like a visualVM.conf file.  And I also did not find the configuration file in my jdk. So how can i solve this error?

Comment: In case of a stand-alone installation, it’s the `etc/visualvm.conf` within the installation directory. For the version shipped with the JDK check for `lib/visualvm/etc/visualvm.conf` within the JDK installation directory. But note that you can also specify options like `-J-Xmx5G` on the command line, to override it for a single run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is a stand-alone installation for me. I solve this by using the command line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two solutions for this :

- 1.using command line to start the JvisualVM, e.g: jvisualvm -J-Xms1024m -J-Xmx2048m
- 2.update the properties in %JDK_HOME%\lib\visualvm\etc\visualvm.conf

Option 1 is more convenient and recommended